# drag and drop is not working on touch screen phones

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

i am using java script ,
my drag and drop is working fine on my pc but when i use on android touch mobiles it is not working  and if i am using jquery then my image is not open on android phone

my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ie=document.all;
var nn6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
var isdrag=false;
var x,y;
var dobj;
function movemouse(e)
{
  if (isdrag)
  {
    dobj.style.left = nn6 ? tx + e.clientX - x : tx + event.clientX - x;
    dobj.style.top  = nn6 ? ty + e.clientY - y : ty + event.clientY - y;
    return false;
  }
}
function selectmouse(e)
{
  var fobj       = nn6 ? e.target : event.srcElement;
  var topelement = nn6 ? "HTML" : "BODY";
  while (fobj.tagName != topelement && fobj.className != "dragme")
  {
    fobj = nn6 ? fobj.parentNode : fobj.parentElement;
  }
  if (fobj.className=="dragme")
  {
    isdrag = true;
    dobj = fobj;
    tx = parseInt(dobj.style.left+0,10);
    ty = parseInt(dobj.style.top+0,10);
    x = nn6 ? e.clientX : event.clientX;
    y = nn6 ? e.clientY : event.clientY;
    document.onmousemove=movemouse;
    return false;
  }
}
document.onmousedown=selectmouse;
document.onmouseup=new Function("isdrag=false");
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Mobile devices don't have mouse, so onmousedown and onmouseup probably won't work. Check out [touch events](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchstart---------event) instead.

That being said, I haven't been able to make touchmove-event to work. Seems like the event is only fired once and touch dragging motion is just ignored.